# How to do dry run with CMake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

With GNU `make`, a dry run can be performed via

```
make -n
```

Is there a similar option for CMake? The best I could come up with is

```
cmake ..
make -n | grep -vi cmake
```

However, I am being too restrictive and am wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [command line syntax](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake.1.html), if you use `--` on the command line with `cmake`, the parameters following that are passed directly to the native build tool. Eg. what you did is somewhat equivalent to this:

```
cmake ..
cmake --build -- -n
```

Comment: Which sort of defeats the purpose of using `cmake --build` in the first place, as you know again have toolchain-specific options in there. But since neither CMake nor all of its supported toolchains offer such a dry-run feature, there is also no way of doing this in a truly portable way.

Comment: The ability to add additional toolchain options pretty useful. While CMake could just add more compiler-specific options, it just unnecessarily complicates CMake. We have a script that drives CMake, and many of those options are essentially embedded in that script, and thus abstracted from the user.

Comment: Oh yes, totally. Don't get me wrong, I think this is a good answer. I just wanted to point out that this solution is not portable, which is not a shortcoming on CMake's side, but simply due to the fact that it's a toolchain-specific feature.

Comment: For Ninja, the flag is -n, too. Pretty convenient.

Comment: This actually doesn't work! That is, the build steps you will get are _not_ those you would get without the `-n` - probaby just some of them.

Comment: especially in ninja `-n` doing nothing actually

Comment: you should add ```-Bn``` which is : ```-B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                              Don't actually run any recipe; just print them.
```